# Executing a stored procedure to populate a table column?

Tags: sql-server

Can I use the `EXEC` keyword to run a stored procedure to populate the `QuestionScore` column?

```
CREATE TABLE Question_Result 
(
     ResultID INT IDENTITY (10000, 1) NOT NULL,
     QResultID VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'QRES' + CAST(NEXT VALUE 
FOR non_identity_incrementer AS VARCHAR(10)),
     QuestionScore DECIMAL (4,2) EXEC dbo.update_question_result_question_score(),
     Assessment INT  NULL,
     DateTimeModified DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ResultID),
     FOREIGN KEY (Assessment) REFERENCES Assessment_Result (ResultID)
);
```

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_question_result_question_score (
    @QuestionScore DECIMAL(4,2) OUTPUT,
    @StudentAnswer NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,
    @AssessingAnswer NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *  
    FROM StudentAnswerQuestionScore

    SET @QuestionScore = (SELECT Score FROM StudentAnswerQuestionScore) 
    SET @StudentAnswer = (SELECT [Student Answer] FROM StudentAnswerQuestionScore) 
    SET @AssessingAnswer = (SELECT [Assessing Answer] FROM StudentAnswerQuestionScore)

    IF (@StudentAnswer = @AssessingAnswer) 
       INSERT INTO Question_Result (QuestionScore) 
       VALUES (@QuestionScore) 
END
```

Comment: what are you actually asking?

Comment: Did you try? What was the result?

Comment: Hi, the error reads Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.update_question_result_question_score", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: No you can't assign your column value like that unless you use a trigger. However, unless `StudentAnswerQuestionScore` contains only a single row, and will only ever contain a single row your stored procedure will result in an error anyway. This could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/179361), it may be beneficial to take a step back, explain what you are trying to achieve, and see if there is a better approach, because that stored procedure looks of very, very, limited use to me.

Comment: I am trying to populate a question score by checking the value of the answer and updating the question score field for that question if it is correct. The procedure runs a view with the info and checks the answer and then should assign the value. I've checked and my stored procedures are in the stored procedures folder

Comment: Thanks Gareth, I was considering using a trigger but then read that a stored procedure is safer. What would be the best approach to update another field based on whether another two fields were equal to each other- student answer to the question and the stored answer to the question which has a stored value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use function for your computed column. Hopefully below codes can give you some ideas:

```
use staging
go

create table Question
(
QuestionKey int identity(1,1),
QuestionDesc varchar(50),
AssignedAnswer varchar(50),
Score int
)
go 

insert into Question
select 'Capital city of AU', 'ACT', 10
go

create function ufnAssignScore (@Question varchar(50), @Answer varchar(50))
Returns int
as
BEGIN

    declare @return int

    select @return = Score
    FROM Question
    where QuestionDesc = @Question and AssignedAnswer = @Answer

    return @return

END
go

create table Answer
(
AnswerKey int identity(1,1),
StudentID varchar(50),
QuestionDesc varchar(50),
AnswerDesc varchar(50),
Score as dbo.ufnAssignScore(QuestionDesc, AnswerDesc)
)
go

insert into Answer (StudentID, QuestionDesc, AnswerDesc)
select 'a1', 'Capital city of AU', 'Mel'
union all
select 'a2', 'Capital city of AU', 'ACT'
go

select * from Answer
```